# How to change title of an event?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I am trying to update the title of the events in the last 7 days in a specific calendar, when an user submits a form.

I have this code now:

```
function myFunction() {

var form = FormApp.openById('1g4gA7glYWRKOVqOi3z3qxyEGbJgaSg_2Jkry_uOp0Cc');
var responses = form.getResponses();
var len = responses.length;
var last = len - 1;
var items = responses[last].getItemResponses();
var email = responses[last].getRespondentEmail();
var equipment = items[1].getResponse();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(equipment);


var d = new Date();
var ms = d.getTime();
var sevenDays = 7*24*60*60*1000;
var minus7daysMs = ms - sevenDays;
var minus7days = new Date(minus7daysMs);
Logger.log('Number of events: ' + minus7days);
var events = cal[0].getEvents(minus7days, d);
var title = events.getName;
Logger.log('Event title: ' + title);
events.setTitle('Returned');
}
```

However, I get that error when running the code: `TypeError: events.setTitle is not a function myFunction  @ update.gs:22`

I tried many different ways of doing it, but it always ends with an error. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your showing script, `getEvents(startTime, endTime)` returns `CalendarEvent[]`. And `setTitle(title)` is a method of Class CalendarEvent. In your script, at `events.setTitle('Returned')`, `setTitle` is used to an array. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. When you want to change all events in `events` with `setTitle('Returned')`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
events.setTitle('Returned');
```

#### To:

```
events.forEach(e => e.setTitle('Returned'));
```

- By this modification, the title of all events in `events` are changed.

#### References:

- [getEvents(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#geteventsstarttime,-endtime)
- [setTitle(title) of Class CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#settitletitle)

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! Now is there a way to change the title of the last event only? I guess forEach must be replaced with something else?

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying and testing it. About your additional question of `Now is there a way to change the title of the last event only?`, in that case, how about modifying `events.forEach(e => e.setTitle('Returned'))` to `events.pop().setTitle('Returned')`? When `pop` is used, the last element can be retrieved. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Comment: Wow, could never have found it by myself, thanks again! One last question, I actually would like to add "Returned" to the event title instead of replacing the whole title with "Replaced". I changed the script to include this: `var title = events.pop().getTitle();
Logger.log('Event title: ' + title);
events.pop().setTitle(title + " Returned");` but I get that error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTitle' of undefined`. Seems like the `title` is not welcomed in `setTitle`?

Comment: I found the solution finally by replacing `.pop()` with `[0]`. Now the last lines look like this: `var oldtitle = events[0].getTitle();
var title = events[0].setTitle(oldtitle + "Returned");`

Comment: @user10879705 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question, when `pop` is used, the array is changed. For example, for `var ar = [1, 2, 3]`, when `ar.pop()` is run and also `ar.pop()` is run, `ar` is `[1]`. This is the reason of your issue. From your 2nd question, I couldn't know your actual situation. So I proposed to use `pop`. I have to apologize that I cannot know the actual situation of your 2nd question.

Comment: @user10879705 If you want to add the title to the last element, please modify to `var event = events.pop(); event.setTitle(event.getTitle() + " Returned");`. By this, you can modify the title of the last element. By the way, `events[0]` is the 1st element of the event. Please be careful this. Although I could resolve your 1st and 2nd questions, if my answer for your 3rd question was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the new comments, it works great now! And no need for apologies, you helped me a lot. And I avoided to include too many information in my first question, to prevent confusion.